# getting Scrambled text using mcrypt for securing url data in php

Tags: php, url, mcrypt

m using

```
public function encrypt($plain_str,$key)
{
     $str= mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plain_str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND));
     $str = urlencode(base64_encode($str));
     return  $str ;
}

public function decrypt($cipher_str,$key)
{
    $str = urldecode(base64_decode($cipher_str));
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND));
}
```

on crypting :`201433~58~g@fds.com~20140820142427`

i get : `%2BAihYMLwpwrsmL4lSGGzwFTfonvdCyOb%2BCGEUJ%2F%2BE%2F7ZnvgwFRYFtlazQeSrVjUjyaaGZADK8%2BZyynIGxyt4VQ%3D%3D`

on decrypting : `%2BAihYMLwpwrsmL4lSGGzwFTfonvdCyOb%2BCGEUJ%2F%2BE%2F7ZnvgwFRYFtlazQeSrVjUjyaaGZADK8%2BZyynIGxyt4VQ%3D%3D`

i get :`201433~58~g@fds.com~20140820142427` back but

when string is malformed like some character removed

like this : `%2BAihYMLwpwrsmL4lSGGzwFTfonvdCyOb%2BCGEUJ%2F%2BE%2F7Z`

on decrypting i get : `201433~58~g@fds.com~201408201424O#¿W«GÝ½Ë‹¯  È#'oP´ŸØw\Ââ¦‘`

How can i detect this anomoly ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to list some flaws in your code:

- [Don't use ECB mode](https://filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/).
- You are encrypting using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, but you're getting the IV size for `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`. (btw, IV is ignored in ECB mode, which is one of the reasons why not to use it)
- You are also using `MCRYPT_RAND` as your randomness source, which is not secure. You should use `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` (that is also the [new default in PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.changed-functions.php#migration56.changed-functions.mcrypt)).
- You don't have to `urlencode()` the resulting ciphertext, Base64 encoding is URL-safe.

Now, to answer your question ... this is done via a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). The easiest way to use a HMAC is to prepend the cipher-text with it (which you should do with the IV as well; don't worry, it's not a secret):

```
public function encrypt($plainText, $encKey, $hmacKey)
{
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size('rijndael-128', 'ctr');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $cipherText = mcrypt_encrypt('rijndael-128', $encKey, $plainText, 'ctr', $iv);

    $cipherText = $iv.$cipherText;
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cipherText, $hmacKey, true);
    return base64_encode($hmac.$cipherText);
}

public function decrypt($cipherText, $encKey, $hmacKey)
{
    $cipherText = base64_decode($cipherText);

    if (strlen($cipherText) <= 32)
    {
        throw new Exception('Authentication failed!');
    }

    $recvHmac = substr($cipherText, 0, 32);
    $cipherText = substr($cipherText, 32);

    $calcHmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cipherText, $hmacKey, true);

    if ( ! hash_equals($recvHmac, $calcHmac))
    {
        throw new Exception('Authentication failed!');
    }

    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size('rijndael-128', 'ctr');
    $iv = substr($cipherText, $ivSize);
    $cipherText = substr($cipherText, $ivSize);

    return mcrypt_decrypt('rijndael-128', $encKey, $cipherText, 'ctr', $iv);
}
```

Please note that the encryption key and HMAC key are different - they *most NOT* be the same key. Also, for Rijndael-128, you should create a 128-bit (or 16-byte) random key, it is not something that you can just type in with your keyboard. Here's how to generate one:

```
$encKey = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```